# print stack with changing values with Thread

Tags: java

How can I know when the thread was stoped and the processor moves to another thread..
Transition between threads harms my calculations, there is some way to know if the thread left and returned to my function?

Comment: What are you trying to do? [XY problem here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: If transition between threads harms your calculations, you really need to redesign your code to be threadsafe. There's lots of tutorial info available about how to do that, via combinations of local variables and threadlocal variables and synchronized blocks and some of the new inherently Atomic classes.

Comment: Post the relevant part of your code and describe the exact problem you're experiencing.  Without it your post will get closed pretty soon.

Answer (score 1):

You can not know when your thread was stopped and the system rescheduled another thread.

But - you can minimize the number of times this event happens by setting the **affinity** of your thread to one of the processors, and the affinities of the other threads to the other processors.

If you are using Linux, you can use [taskset](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/setting-processor-affinity-certain-task-or-process.html) for each thread in the system (get the list by "ps -e") to set the affinities of the other threads to other processors.

This will decrease the load on the processor and will cause it to context-switch less times.

Comment: If you want to know exactly how many times your thread was scheduled out, you can use the perf tool:
https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page

Again, only in Linux...

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is - you can't. Even if you could detect thread context switches it happens far too often to usefully logged.

A better question would be to look at why you need to know. If there is a problem there post it as a question and we can solve the real issue.